# $watchCollection and multiple expressions doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two arrays and every array has booleans values, I tried to use the $watchCollecion function to show a message when some change happens in one of the those arrays but for some reason it doesn't work.

I would like to see what's wrong with this [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Wj3ICWeY17E2q0SlXk5z?p=preview)

*Controller*

```
  $scope.arrayCategoryA = [];
  $scope.arrayCategoryB = [];

  $scope.$watchCollection(['arrayCategoryA', 'arrayCategoryB'], function(newVal, oldVal, scope){
    console.log("something changed");
  }, true);

  $http.get("categoryA.json").success(function(data) {
     $scope.categoryA = data;
     for (var i = 0; i < $scope.categoryA.length; i++) 
     $scope.arrayCategoryA[i] = true;
  });

  $http.get("categoryB.json").success(function(data) {
     $scope.categoryB = data;
     for (var j = 0; j < $scope.categoryB.length; j++) 
     $scope.arrayCategoryB[j] = true;
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> AngularJS has always had a Scope.$watch() function as means to observe
>   [and react to] changes in a given value. With AngularJS 1.1.4,
>   however, they added the Scope.$watchCollection() function as a means
>   to observe changes in a collection (either as an Array or an Object).

$watchCollection will work only for one array or object.So you have to change your code to single watch.

```
$scope.$watchCollection('arrayCategoryA', function(newVal, oldVal){
    console.log("something changed 1");
}, true);
$scope.$watchCollection('arrayCategoryB', function(newVal, oldVal){
    console.log("something changed 2");
}, true);
```